# Enable CORs for all upstream server locations

Tags: nginx

NginX Newbie.

I want to use NginX as a reverse proxy for websphere libery appserver on the same machine running on port 9080.

I want all requests to come thru NginX and all responses to enable CORs.

I got this to work but there is a lot of repetition in my nginx conf. How do I re-use CORs config across all locations?

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name $host;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:9080;

    location = / {
        [ CORs configuration ]
    }

    location /two/ {
        [ CORs configuration repeated ]
    }

    location /three/ {
        [ CORs configuration repeated again ]
    }
}
```

Comment: You'd have to define the reverse proxy target (upstream server) and tell nginx to set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to `'*'`. That should do the trick.. What have you tried so far?

Comment: updated comment with what I tried but a lot of repetition

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set cors options in the server block so you don't have to repeat it for every location:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name $host;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:9080;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';

location = / {...
```

Excerpt from the nginx documentation:

> Syntax:   add_header name value [always];
>
> Default:  —
>
> Context:  http, server, location, if in location

Comment: It looks like your example misses the `add_header` directive, or is this special nginx syntax when adding headers in the server block?